# Problems with Firebase and google chrome when try to send a cloud messaging

Tags: firebase, google-chrome, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, push

I'm trying to send cloud messaging with firebase, I'm using a simple code to get the token and receive the push message, when run the code in localhost and I do the test with another browser like edge or firefox it works, the push message is received, but when I do the test in chrome the program receive the token but the notification never is received,
I have and index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Firebase Cloud Messaging Example</title>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.1/firebase-messaging.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Firebase Cloud Messaging Example</h1>

  <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

An app.js

```
// Initialize Firebase
const firebaseConfig = {
    // Your app's Firebase configuration object
....
};

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const messaging = firebase.messaging();

messaging.getToken({ vapidKey: '...' })
    .then((currentToken) => {
        if (currentToken) {
            // Use the token to send notifications to the user
            console.log('FCM Token:', currentToken);
        } else {
            // Show permission request UI
            console.log('No registration token available.');
        }
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log('An error occurred while retrieving token.', error);
    });

messaging.requestPermission()
    .then(() => {
        console.log('Notification permission granted.');
        // Handle user permission granted
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log('Unable to get permission to notify.', error);
        // Handle permission denied
    });

messaging.onMessage((payload) => {
    console.log('Received message:', payload);
    // Handle received message/notification
});
```

And I see for example in firefox the browser send and problem or error with an file firebase-messaging-sw but for example edge the browser don't get error, wherever I use this code to this file

```
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.1/firebase-app.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.1/firebase-messaging.js');

firebase.initializeApp({
  // Your app's Firebase configuration object
  ...
});

const messaging = firebase.messaging();

messaging.onBackgroundMessage((payload) => {
  console.log('Received background message:', payload);

  // Customize the notification here
  const notificationTitle = 'Background Message Title';
  const notificationOptions = {
    body: 'Background Message body.',
    icon: '/path/to/icon.png'
    // Add more options as needed
  };

  self.registration.showNotification(notificationTitle, notificationOptions);
});
```

I'm not sure if there is a problem with my code or there is a problem with firebase and chrome, if you can help me I will be gratefull:)

I need to know why mi code its not working with google chrome and firebase, maybe my logic if failing or there is a problem with these tecnologies.